# How to find obsolete plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I just installed a brand new copy of QGIS 1.8 Lisboa and all of the associated software on a Windows Vista PC using the Windows Osgeo4W QGIS installer, and I get this message:

"*The Plugin Installer has detected an obsolete plugin which masks a newer version shipped with this QGIS version. This is likely due to files associated with a previous installation of QGIS. Please use the Plugin Installer to remove that older plugin in order to unmask the newer version shipped with this copy of QGIS*."

I did have an older copy of QGIS but I uninstalled it and I am 99% certain that I successfully deleted all of the associated files and directories.  I notice that the Osgeo4W directories created by the OSGEO4W installer include several versions of QGIS (including 1.0 and 1.4), but I am a novice user and don't know how to figure out which plugin is causing trouble, or if this could be a bug in the Osgeo4w installer.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the error window title used to contain some information on the plugin causing such trouble. Have you checked?

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the .qgis folder in your user path. Thats where the plugins are stored.

Comment: Well that is if you want to remove everything but a bit brute force to remove everything if it's just one plugin.  Also if you do this only delete the `\python\plugins` folder

Comment: Thank you both -- is there any way to tell which plugin is obsolete?

Comment: Does Plugins -> Fetch Python Plugins... show a list that tells you what is installed? Does anything have status "invalid"?

Comment: Thanks BradHards, and apologies for the delayed response -- was away for a couple of days.  I just tried that and there is a plugin called "Plugin Installer" that is upgradeable from 1.0.1.0->1.1, but when I try to upgrade I get the message "Failed to unzip the plugin package. Probably it's broken or missing from the repository."